# Why converting a string path to Geometry and back again throws a FormatException?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, type-conversion, pathgeometry

I need to convert a string path to a [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Geometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and back again.

The first step is to convert my path: `"M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"`. To do this I use the [Geoemtry.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.parse.aspx) method, that creates a new Geometry instance from the specified string:

```
var geometry = Geometry.Parse("M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z");
```

Of this geometry I need to store, in my data structure, its path, that I get using the `Geometry.ToString` method:

```
string str = geometry.ToString();
// And this is my str: "M100;100L300;100 200;300z"
```

Now I want to recreate the same geometry using the stored path, therefore I use again the `Grometry.Parse` method:

```
// Here i get a FormatException
var geometry2 = Geometry.Parse(str);
```

The problem is I get a `FormatException`!
How is it possible? How can I fix it?

Comment: Turn "M100;100L300;100 200;300z" into "M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z". Remove the semicolon and try it out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is the problem with the `Culture` of your machine as it is set to some other `culture` than `en-Us`. Because the path values should be comma/space seperated in order to be parsed while in your case `ToString()` is returning the semi colon seperated values. Try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` while converting the `Geometry` to `string`. It will fix the exception

```
string str = geometry.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```